# Characteristic Path Length for a 1-lattices

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation, network

I do not understand how to obtain the stated formula for the **characteristic path length (L)** of a $1$-lattice, as well as its **clustering coefficient**. The following text is taken from *The Small World Phenomenon* by Duncan Watts.

---

**Definition** The *characteristic path length* (L) of a graph is the median of the means of the shortest path lengths connecting each vertex $v\in V(G)$ to all other vertices. That is, calculate $d(v,j),\forall j\in V(G)$ and find $\overline{d}_v$ for each $v$. Then define $L$ as the median of $\{\overline{d}_v\}$.

A $d$-lattice is a labelled, unweighted, undirected simple graph that is similar to a Euclidean cubic lattice of dimension $d$ in that any vertex $v$ is joined to its lattice neighbours $u_i$ and $w_i$ are specified by 
\begin{eqnarray}
u_i&=&\left[\left(v-i^{d^{'}} \right)+n\right] \mod n \\
w_i&=&\left( v+i^{d^{'}}\right) \mod n
\end{eqnarray}

where $1\le i\le \frac{k}{2}, 1\le d^{'}\le d$ and $k\ge 2d$. Below is an illustration of a $1$-lattice with $k=4$.
$\hskip2in$[image]

For a $1$-lattice with even $k\ge 2$, the characteristic path length is 
$$
L = \frac{n(n+k-2)}{2k(n-1)}
$$

Its clustering coefficient is 
$$
\gamma =\frac{3}{4}\left( \frac{k-2}{k-1}\right)
$$

Answer (score 1):

From what I can gather, since each vertex is isomorphic in a one lattice, L is just the mean of shortest path lengths between a vertex v and any other vertex.

The (n-1) part of the denominator comes from the fact that this is a mean of paths between n-1 vertices. Number these other vertices one through n-1. Their summed distance will be: $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} ceiling(\frac{min(i,n-i)}{k/2})$, the numerator represents the distance of this was just a cycle, not a 1-lattice, and the k represents the maximum cycle distance you may travel. Intuitively, the numerator should be ~n(n-1)/4, consequence of its resemblance of an arithmetic sum, meanwhile the denominator is k/2.

$\frac{n(n-1)/4}{k/2} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2k}$

This largely accounts for the terms in the characteristic path length. The +n(k-1)/2k should arise from cleaning up details like the ceiling function.

Comment: Apologies if this is too informal, I am very tired and can clarify if needed.